# Directive to insert button in mat-paginator: icon not rendering

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive, paginator

I want to insert a button between "previous page" and "next page" in a mat-paginator component, and for that I wrote a directive that does the job of injecting the paginator and its DOM reference, and doing the proper insertions using Angular's `Renderer2`. It works, with exception of these two fails:

- <s>SVG icon is not rendered (button works but appears blank)</s> ***(solved, see edit)***;
- ToolTip is not shown.

Could someone take a look and tell what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

[Link to my code in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/paginator-refresh-button-angular-material-17?devToolsHeight=33&file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Fpaginator-refresh.directive.ts)

#### EDIT

The problem with icon not rendering was solved by adding the 'svg' namespace to elements <svg> and <path> (thanks, reddit).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve by creating a new `MatToolTip` on the fly.

**Check [solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/paginator-refresh-button-angular-material-17-t86sk1?devToolsHeight=33&file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Fpaginator-refresh.directive.ts)**, please look at the constructor's parameters and the `attachMatToolTip()` method.

Any improvement suggestions are more than welcome!